# How can I get autofill to work when using pytest fixtures that yield?

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest

I have the following setup for a Page Object Model framework I'm trying to build :

**conftest.py :**

```
import pytest

from common.models.web_rewrite.driver_factory import WebDriverFactory
from common.models.web_rewrite.userdata_page import UserdataPage


@pytest.fixture(scope="class", autouse=True)
def setup(request):
    factory = WebDriverFactory()
    driver = factory.create_driver(browser="Chrome")
    userdata_page = UserdataPage(driver)
    request.cls.factory = factory
    request.cls.driver = driver
    request.cls.userdata_page = userdata_page
    yield
    factory.quit_driver(driver)
```

**test_base.py**

```
import pytest
from common.models.web_rewrite.userdata_page import UserdataPage


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
class BaseTest:
    pass
```

**test_userdata_form.py**

```
from tests.vi_rewrite.test_base import BaseTest
class TestUserdataPage(BaseTest):

    def test_open_userdata(self):
        self.userdata_page.open_userdata_page().fill_transaction_no()

    def test_change_trans_no(self):
        self.userdata_page.open_userdata_page().fill_transaction_no()
```

*The tests are just some actions to try things out, they don't necessarily make sense*

All of this works just fine if I run the tests, the problem I'm having is that I have no autofill in the test methods for the instances of the pages created in the fixture.
PyCharm discovers the methods from the instances just fine ( ctrl + click on open_userdata_page for example ) but there is no auto-fill.

[No declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rOfx.png)

I tried using a module scope in the fixture but that didn't solve it either.
I'm trying to avoid returning all the instances in the fixture or creating the instances in the test methods.